# Algorithm to see if regex repeat is reducible

Tags: regex, algorithm, language-agnostic

I'm looking for an algorithm that can check if nested regex repeats are reducible. Assume that parsing the regex is already done.

#### Example:

```
(1{1,2}){1,2} === 1{1,4}
    It matches 1, 11, 111, 1111 which can be rewritten as a single repeat

(1{2,2}){1,2} can not be reduced
    It matches 11 and 1111 which can not be rewritten as a single repeat.

(1{10,11}){1,2} can not be reduced

(1{10,19}){1,2} === 1{10,38}

(1{1,2}){10,11} === 1{10,22}

(1{10,11})* can not be reduced

(1*){10,11} === 1*
```

I've been trying to find a pattern to this type of operation without having to match all possible solutions and look for holes that would prevent it from being reduced. There must be a simple function (`f( A, B, C, D ) -> ( E, F )`) that could solve an arbitrary input like this:

```
(1{A,B}){C,D} -> 1{E,F}
```

Comment: Note that: `(1{1,2}){1,2}` matches only *1, 11, 11, 1111* so !==  `1{1,4}`; also `(1{2,2}){1,2}` can first be reduced to `(1{2}){1,2}` then `11{1,2}`; also `(1{10,19}){1,2}` is not equivalent to `1{10,38}` because odds in range `1{21}`...`1{37}` can't be represented in the  'long form' (eg. `(1{10.5}){2}` is not possible)

Comment: @kaᵠ

This is not true. `(1{1,2}){1,2}` is perfectly equivalent to `1{1,4}`. This is because the first group's repeat is allow to change in between uses. `(1{1,2}){1,2}` === `(1{1,2})(1{1,2})?` === `(1{1,2})(1{0,2})` === `11?1?1?` === `1{1,4}`. Try it if you don't believe me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// (x{A,B}){C,D} -> x{E,F}
bool SimplifyNestedRepetition(int A, int B,
                              int C, int D,
                              out int E, out int F)
{
    if (B == -1 || C == D || A*(C+1) <= B*C + 1)
    {
        E = A*C;

        if (B == -1 || D == -1) F = -1;
        else F = B*D;

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

- If `x{A,B}` is unlimited, it can be repeated any number of times.
- `(x{A,B}){C}` is always reducible.
- If `A*(C+1) <= B*C + 1`, you can reduce it, since there are no gap between the longest sequence of `C` repetitions, and the shortest sequence of `C+1` repetitions.

`B = -1` or `D == -1` means unlimited, like `x*` or `x{5,}`.

---

### Test cases:

```
Input           Reducible?
(x{0,0}){0,0}   Yes - x{0,0}
(x{0,1}){0,0}   Yes - x{0,0}
(x{0,2}){0,0}   Yes - x{0,0}
(x{1,1}){0,0}   Yes - x{0,0}
(x{1,2}){0,0}   Yes - x{0,0}
(x{1,3}){0,0}   Yes - x{0,0}
(x{2,2}){0,0}   Yes - x{0,0}
(x{2,3}){0,0}   Yes - x{0,0}
(x{2,4}){0,0}   Yes - x{0,0}
(x{0,0}){0,1}   Yes - x{0,0}
(x{0,1}){0,1}   Yes - x{0,1}
(x{0,2}){0,1}   Yes - x{0,2}
(x{1,1}){0,1}   Yes - x{0,1}
(x{1,2}){0,1}   Yes - x{0,2}
(x{1,3}){0,1}   Yes - x{0,3}
(x{2,2}){0,1}   No 
(x{2,3}){0,1}   No 
(x{2,4}){0,1}   No 
(x{0,0}){0,2}   Yes - x{0,0}
(x{0,1}){0,2}   Yes - x{0,2}
(x{0,2}){0,2}   Yes - x{0,4}
(x{1,1}){0,2}   Yes - x{0,2}
(x{1,2}){0,2}   Yes - x{0,4}
(x{1,3}){0,2}   Yes - x{0,6}
(x{2,2}){0,2}   No 
(x{2,3}){0,2}   No 
(x{2,4}){0,2}   No 
(x{0,0}){1,1}   Yes - x{0,0}
(x{0,1}){1,1}   Yes - x{0,1}
(x{0,2}){1,1}   Yes - x{0,2}
(x{1,1}){1,1}   Yes - x{1,1}
(x{1,2}){1,1}   Yes - x{1,2}
(x{1,3}){1,1}   Yes - x{1,3}
(x{2,2}){1,1}   Yes - x{2,2}
(x{2,3}){1,1}   Yes - x{2,3}
(x{2,4}){1,1}   Yes - x{2,4}
(x{0,0}){1,2}   Yes - x{0,0}
(x{0,1}){1,2}   Yes - x{0,2}
(x{0,2}){1,2}   Yes - x{0,4}
(x{1,1}){1,2}   Yes - x{1,2}
(x{1,2}){1,2}   Yes - x{1,4}
(x{1,3}){1,2}   Yes - x{1,6}
(x{2,2}){1,2}   No 
(x{2,3}){1,2}   Yes - x{2,6}
(x{2,4}){1,2}   Yes - x{2,8}
(x{0,0}){1,3}   Yes - x{0,0}
(x{0,1}){1,3}   Yes - x{0,3}
(x{0,2}){1,3}   Yes - x{0,6}
(x{1,1}){1,3}   Yes - x{1,3}
(x{1,2}){1,3}   Yes - x{1,6}
(x{1,3}){1,3}   Yes - x{1,9}
(x{2,2}){1,3}   No 
(x{2,3}){1,3}   Yes - x{2,9}
(x{2,4}){1,3}   Yes - x{2,12}
(x{0,0}){2,2}   Yes - x{0,0}
(x{0,1}){2,2}   Yes - x{0,2}
(x{0,2}){2,2}   Yes - x{0,4}
(x{1,1}){2,2}   Yes - x{2,2}
(x{1,2}){2,2}   Yes - x{2,4}
(x{1,3}){2,2}   Yes - x{2,6}
(x{2,2}){2,2}   Yes - x{4,4}
(x{2,3}){2,2}   Yes - x{4,6}
(x{2,4}){2,2}   Yes - x{4,8}
(x{0,0}){2,3}   Yes - x{0,0}
(x{0,1}){2,3}   Yes - x{0,3}
(x{0,2}){2,3}   Yes - x{0,6}
(x{1,1}){2,3}   Yes - x{2,3}
(x{1,2}){2,3}   Yes - x{2,6}
(x{1,3}){2,3}   Yes - x{2,9}
(x{2,2}){2,3}   No 
(x{2,3}){2,3}   Yes - x{4,9}
(x{2,4}){2,3}   Yes - x{4,12}
(x{0,0}){2,4}   Yes - x{0,0}
(x{0,1}){2,4}   Yes - x{0,4}
(x{0,2}){2,4}   Yes - x{0,8}
(x{1,1}){2,4}   Yes - x{2,4}
(x{1,2}){2,4}   Yes - x{2,8}
(x{1,3}){2,4}   Yes - x{2,12}
(x{2,2}){2,4}   No 
(x{2,3}){2,4}   Yes - x{4,12}
(x{2,4}){2,4}   Yes - x{4,16}
```

Comment: This is not 100% correct. For example `(x{2,5}){2}` gives `x{4,10}`, but the original pattern cannot match odd numbers of `x`s. Another example would be `(x{y,z}){1}`, which can always be reduced to `x{y,z}`.

Comment: "cannot match odd numbers" — sure it can. It is equivalent to `x{2,5}x{2,5}`. You don't have to select the same number of occurrences in both subpatterns. Check it with `echo xxxxxxx | egrep '(x{2,5}){2}'`.

Comment: @n.m. not sure what I was thinking :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using `advanced' regexp features like backlinks then regexpes are just finite state automata, a simple version of state machines. They have the very nice property that for all FSAs, there exist *one unique* smallest FSA, and it's even pretty easy to find it: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)

While your problem seems more specific, I'm sure it could be useful to look at some of the minimization algorithms described within.

Comment: I'm actually already doing this type of stuff in the library I'm working on, but this type of operation is *way* to expensive. Converting from a regex -> NFA -> DFA is `2^n`.

Comment: In my case I'm trying to make an optimizer to take a DFA and output a regex, but often I end up with patterns like the one in this question and I want to output the smallest possible regex.